# Getting invalid syntax in Python Parser of labeling in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, labeling, python-parser

I am writing a Python expression in order to label gravity mains based on their attributes. I will provide screenshots of the specific error and my attribute table's field settings for reference.

[image: Attribute Table Settings]
[image: Error Message]

```
def FindLabel ( [PipeHeight], [PipeWidth], [PipeShape] [MATERIAL] ):
    labelText=''
    if isinstance( [PipeShape], str):
        if [PipeShape] == 'Circular':
            if isinstance( [PipeHeight], float):
                labelText= '{d}"'.format([PipeHeight])
        elif [PipeShape] == 'Elliptical':
            if isinstance( [PipeHeight], float) and isinstance( [PipeWidth], float):
                labelText= '{d}"x{d}"'.format([PipeHeight], [PipeWidth])

    if isinstance( [MATERIAL], str):
        if len(labelText) > 0:
            labelText += ' '
        labelText += '{}'.format([MATERIAL])
    else:
        if len(labelText) > 0:
            labelText += ' '
        labelText += 'Ukn'

    return  [PipeHeight], [PipeWidth], [PipeShape] [MATERIAL] 
        labelText
```

I am very new to writing Python code and had assistance with a programmer getting it this far.  Unfortunately, we can't get past this error.

Comment: I think you’re missing two commas on what should be a single return line.

Comment: To compliment @PolyGeo, you also need a coma between [PipeShape] [MATERIAL] in the FindLabel function parameter declaration section.

Comment: Thanks! I added the commas between [PipeShape] [MATERIAL] in the FindLabel function, where would the two commas go in the return though? I know one would be between [PipeShape] [MATERIAL]. Does one go after [MATERIAL] too?

Comment: Just `return labelText`. Don't `return [all] [input] [arguments]` (which is not what Arc is expecting) then a newline then an indented `labelText` (which is a SyntaxError)

Comment: I'm now getting a new error that the name 'FindLabel' is not defined.. I've added the missing comma in my FindLabel line (line 1), and edited the end following the last comment that user2856 suggested and still having problems creating these labels.